# C# Tcp Ip identification of clients

Tags: c#, client-server, tcp

I have a Tcp Ip client/server connection.
I want the server to be able to identify the client through an Id and a string.
To do that following and expanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069278/identification-of-clients) I have created

```
public class MySocket
{
    private static int Counter = 0;

    public int UniqueId
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string StrIdentificator;

    protected Socket socket
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #region functions
    ....
    #endregion


    public MySocket(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, string strIdentification)
    {
        socket = new Socket(socketType, protocolType);

        if (socket == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient null");
        }
        this.socket = socket;
        this.UniqueId = ++MySocket.Counter;
        this.StrIdentificator = strIdentification;
    }
}
```

I am therefore passing this as an object:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
int port = 11000;
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

// Create a TCP/IP Mysocket.<----------here is where I store more data
var MyClient = new MySocket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp, "BBBB");

// Connect to the remote endpoint.
MyClient.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), MyClient);
connectDone.WaitOne();
```

so, instead of passing a Socket I pass a MySocket which holds more data.

That part works properly for the client.
For the server part instead I have to retrieve that object

```
// Get the socket that handles the client request.
Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
```

now this is where the problem arises. Is there any way to retrieve a MySocket instead than a socket?

Thank you in advance
Patrick

Comment: can't you implement your `ConnectComplete` event in your own `MySocket` class and raise it when required, you can pass `this` instance as state if required

Comment: _"Is there any way to retrieve a MySocket instead than a socket?"_ No. What do you need that kind of identification for?

Comment: @Alexey On Server side, it still will always be a `Socket`, not a `MySocket`.

Comment: @Fildor right, but this does not matter IMO, since `EndAccept` is performed inside own class, so, we know where it exactly is, just use wrapper 'MySocket'

Comment: @Alexey And then? You still won't have the values of the additional fields out of the box. That's why I asked what it is used for, so I can make a sophisticated suggestion. In other words: "Smells like X-Y".

Comment: The code you linked is intended to be used by server, not by client. On client it's useless.

Comment: @Evk do you mean the other way round? It works on client, don't know how to make it work on server

Comment: @Fildor if I have more than one client connecting how can I identify which one is connected to the server?

Comment: One Client = one Socket instance. So if you want to identify a specific client, it should identify itself on connection through some sort of communication protocol.

Comment: Ok so that protocol is not intended for something like a chat is it? it's more like something point to point

Comment: Whatever you make it. You can chose to use some existing protocol that fits your requirements ( in that case, there will probably be libs that implement it ) or you could make your own. BTW: What I wrote above is not entirely accurate. You _can_ in fact have multiple Sockets from the same client. But the "identify through protocol" still stands.